# How do I understand report published in console tab after simulation in Xlinx?

Tags: verilog, simulation, xilinx

The report is :

Started : "Simulate Behavioral Model".

Number of CPUs detected in this system: 2
Turning on mult-threading, number of parallel sub-compilation jobs: 4

Starting static elaboration
Completed static elaboration
Fuse Memory Usage: 65712 KB
**Fuse CPU Usage: 311 ms

Time Resolution for simulation is 1ps.**
Waiting for 2 sub-compilation(s) to finish...
Compiled 10 Verilog Units
**Fuse Memory Usage: 72948 KB

Fuse CPU Usage: 390 ms**

ISim simulation engine GUI launched successfully

Process "Simulate Behavioral Model" completed successfully

What is this fuse CPU and Memory usage. Do anyone have any idea about it. I googled but did not get satisfactory things related to it.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iSim compiler is called fuse[.exe]. The result is an executable that is launched and connected to console (std_in and std_out) or to iSim[.exe] the simulator GUI.

So your report line of interest is about fuse's system resource consumption.

Comment: Thank you. what does Fuse CPU Usage: 390 ms means? 390 ms .. does ms=millisecond?

Comment: Yes, the CPU was active for 390 milliseconds (ms).

Comment: Do it give any information related simulation time too?

Comment: No it's just an information how much CPU time was wasted. I'm not sure if these values are correct, but I have never tested it.

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding how can we calculate the processing time of verilog code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I have simulations that compile over 2 minutes.

Comment: ok so how can we do time performance analysis of verilog code or our hardware generated by verilog code?

Comment: Why would one do that? Yes you could check the compile time needed but it does not say any thing about simulation runtime nor synthesis compile time nor how fast your circuit is. E.g. synthesis uses several random number based heuristic algorithms. In big designs it can be seen in register utilisation +-10 registers. The runtime is also very blurry.